# How would you name a "mechanical pencil" in Esperanto?

Tags: word-choice

These are named ["mechanical pencils"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_pencil) in English, but some other languages use the term "lead holder" (eg. French : *portemine*). 
What word in esperanto would be the most understood?

Comment: Please avoid posting copyrighted images on Stack Exchange sites. Try to find an alternative images that is in the public domain or available under Creative Commons (like the content of this site), or use a photograph that you made yourself.

Comment: I have replaced the image with a link to Wikipedia, which provides another photo of various mechanical pencils.

Comment: FWIW, in English, I have always understood "mechanical pencil" and "lead holder" to be different things. Indeed, I have been given the advice to get a lead holder instead of a mechanical pencil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By coincidence, we were discussing this very question on Facebook in the *Lingva Konsultejo* just a few days ago. While PIV lists *ĉukkrajono* and *puŝkrajono* several people commented that these terms were not clear (especially before it was clear that I was quoting PIV and not simply making them up.)

The only alternative which was made was "reŝargebla krajono" - which seems OK to me. It seems you could also call it "reuzebla". In spite of what it says in PIV, it doesn't seem like there is a single stable term for mechanical pencil.

Answer (score 1):

According to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#%C4%89ukkrajono): **ĉukkrajono**. Puŝkrajono, kies grafitaĵo estas tenata per ĉuketo.

See also:

[https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ĉukkrajono](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C4%89ukkrajono)

https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vortaro_angla-Esperanta_c

Answer (score 0):

These days the distinction between *krajono* and *plumo* is somewhat outdated and artificial. They all are *skribiloj*. This is also reflected in some languages, where all are called *skribiloj* and only if necessary, a defining part is added. Esperanto works that way on many cases by preferring compound words and adjective attributes instead of separate words.

So

- globskribilo
- grafitaĵa skribilo
- reŝargebla skribilo, ŝraŭbskribilo, puŝskribilo
- inkoskribilo